# Zoom based on node count

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I want to implement auto zoom feature based on number of nodes available on chart.Currently nodes are being fetched from api and vary on number based on request to server.

I have tried following code:

```
//limit scale to max 1.5 and min limit to 0.4
function zoomer(){
    scale = ((height/7)/total_node_count) ;
    scale = scale > 1 ? 0.6 : scale
    scale = scale >= 1.0 && scale <= 0.6 ? scale - 0.3 : scale
    scale = scale <= 0.4 ? 0.4 : scale
}
```

It works well but it do not cover all edge cases, I want to try out something with domain and range like:

```
scale_range = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,1000]).range([10,0.2])
scale = scale_range(all_data.nodes.length)
```

So that it zooms in or out based on number of nodes in every scenario.